# How do I split an array element by commas into something else like a new array

Tags: ruby

So far I've loaded an entire file into an array (1 line per array element). Then I've learned how to search for the correct lines needed. Now I need to split those lines so I can use the data.

1 array element (1 line from file):
data,data,data,data,data

The first data column is text, the others are numbers.
How do I from here split this data into something so I can do math on just one of these columns or plus 2 together, ect ?

As just a secondary note. I have a file with thousands of lines. But I'm picking 20 elements at a time. So I need to do this for 20 elements that are next to each other. So array[56],57,58, ect.

So I can then do math on row 1 column2 - row 3 column 4. Ect. (if this were set up in excel it would be like this - but you get the point - but it can be set up in any way as long as I can know how to get to individual data)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So as an example of how I try to troubleshoot this. I do find things like split. But then what do I do with it. I've been able to split data but how do I name the data something so I can point to it? And what kind of data structure would I use? Just stuff like this I'm still learning thats why I'm asking a kinda noob question. I just started programming. Hopefully I'll be soon able to do most simple things inefficiently and then learn later how to do them better. Isn't that how it works? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [String::split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split).

```
"1,2,3,4,a,b,c,d".split(',')         #=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

You can then convert the array elements to integers or floats as needed, as in

```
str = "1,2,3,4,a,b,c,d"
arr = str.split(",")

i = arr[0].to_i
f = arr[1].to_f
```

Additionally, if you are working with CSV files, you might consider using [Ruby's CSV library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html).

Comment: yeah but my starting data looks like this: array[57] - so I would do array[57].split(',') ? And then what? Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: Assuming that array[57] is a string containing a line from your file, then yes, you can call array[57].split(',').

Answer (score 1):

The file structure you've described is similar to [`csv`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) files. To parse csv file in ruby, you can use the *surprise*... CSV library which is part of std library of ruby.

```
require 'CSV'
data = CSV.read(path_to_your_csv_file)
```

Now, you have your data loaded. To iterate over large blocks each time you can use [`each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons)

```
data.each_cons(20) do |rows| 
  #do something
end
```